# CSS-Confusion: Website has a lot of blank space on right side

Tags: html, css

Can't seem to figure this out...

This website, http://dannyvola.com, has a lot of blank space on the right side.

I know its something small but I can't figure it out!

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: looks reasonable to me. can you be more specific?

Comment: I see a centered layout with the same amount of space on the left and right side. Please clarify your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with the following css:

```
#thumbnav {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 4px 0 0 0;
    width: 20000px;  <-- HERE
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
}
```

You are giving the element a width of 20000px which is pushing your layout out to the right. A loooong way to the right!

Try changing the `width` to `auto`.

Comment: Bet me to it, the fix is very simple, just add `#module-slideshow { overflow: hidden; }` and hide that long block of space.